# Has anyone used version control on PeopleSoft?

Tags: version-control, peoplesoft

We are looking at installing version control. We have found three that integrate with PeopleSoft: Phire, Grey Sparling, and Stat. Has anyone used these, and what experiences do you have with them?

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of experience with STAT, but not the other products.

The product does indeed succeed on its promise to deliver a change control system for PeopleSoft; versioning for objects, check in/check out, restore, etc.

The user interface, however, often makes me want to run screaming while pulling all my hair out.  It's clunky, ugly, and requires way too many clicks to get something done.  In a nutshell, it gets in your way.

Migrations (to UAT and prod) have been simplified for sure, but we also spent a lot of time up front writing our own post-migration processing scripts to fill in the gaps of things STAT does not do out of the box:   building a project, granting permissions to database tables as necessary, execute data mover scripts and/or sql....   These are all things that generally happen on a migration.   STAT provides "hooks" for events to occur, but it's kind of clunky out of the box.

So from a migrator or auditor perspective, it's awesome.

From a user perspective, it causes pain and slows the development process.

Comment: After reading Mike P's answer, I must concede that there are some benefits for the developer as well.  The version control aspect and ability to recover to a specific version when you screw things up is a nice feature, all clunkiness aside.

Answer (score 1):

We switched from Stat to Phire and have been very happy. Phire runs on the same architecture as PeopleSoft, so there is no fat client software and the interface is much more user friendly. Also, Phire has features such as automating project build and running SQL and DMS scripts. Our developers actually like Phire because it provides for much better code comparison reports and easy access to previous code versions. Our migrators  love it because it makes migrations so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Stat! is the best and most expensive.  There appear to be more coming on the market at lower prices.

Comment: I have seen the prices on the others.   If they are the cheap ones...  WOW!

Answer (score 0):

I concur 100% with Chip L.  Stat is excellent for a migrator or auditor, but clunky.

Clunkyness aside, the ability to sync App Designer projects into a Stat CSR is very nice.  For example, you can load up a project, start developing, adding new objects, etc. then just hop over to Stat, click "Sync Project" and Stat now has all your objects and (pending any object contention) is ready for you to snapshot.